# If table has 5 million rows, how long would it take for MySQL to search for a row using an ID?

Tags: performance

Will the number of rows affect MySQL from performing a query such as:

SELECT * FROM table WHERE c_id = 2

c_id is primary unique key & auto-increments every record.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer is no, assuming there is an index on c_id.

Longer answer:

IF there is enough available memory the index will be loaded into memory and that will make the lookup essentially instant (in the milliseconds).

HOWEVER, the record lookup is not the same as the fetch of the actual data.  MySQL first FINDS the data and then it GETS the data.

The fetch step speed depends on:

1. Number of records
2. Number of columns
3. Column types
4. Hard drive speed
5. Amount of memory available to store recent queries
6. Whether or not the data has been recently queried

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

It will have some negligible effect to performance, and as always it will depend on your hardware and resources available, but it shouldn't be a problem if you are just querying the primary key as MySQL (and most DB engines) index it by default.